# How do I develop the offline mode of my Android application?

Tags: android

I have developed the Android app using REST API so the back end handles all the business logic but it works only when the mobile is having internet, if internet is not working for some reason then my application is of no use, hence need to develop the offline mode logic so if internet is connected or not  my application has to work.

I can do one thing in offline mode the application saved the data locally but when it comes online it has to send the data to the database automatically,  so need to build that logic.

Comment: You can use `SQLite, Realm` and for small operations can use `SharedPreference` as well which will work offline as well

Comment: i know but the question is how do i use it so the application will works in both online in and in offline mode

Comment: you need `caching mechanism` or `offline database` ?

Comment: i want offline database and what caching mechanism is?

Comment: @akshaypatil, It seems you are a beginner. You will have to put the data into the database as API gives the response and have to make logic if there is a record on the database pull all out the data and show according to your requirement either have a network or not.

Comment: ok consider a record is present in main database and if i have send same record in local db where the network is not available so then in app it will show that record entered successfully but when device come online need to push data to main db so at that time will have a problem not able to enter same record in db

Comment: @akshay patil, you must have some unique column according to that you can put the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple steps to follow to achieve offline capabilities.

**Loading the data:**

You need to take a look at Jetpack for cues about the [app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide). Building an architecture similar to that help you provide offline capabilities in your app.

That is the first case where the data is getting loaded from the local database or the server when the user opens the application.

**Updating the server data:**

During the offline, save the entries to the local db. Listen to the connectivity changes using a Job Scheduler or Work Manager (or create a periodic job or work that runs every day with constraint being internet connectivity) to sync the data with the server.

**Sync across devices**

If the user is logged in multiple devices then send FCM Notification to the other devices to pull the updated data.

Answer (score 3):

You have not mention which Network library you have used to make API calling.

So one suggesion is to use **[Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit)** from squere

Retrofit also provide **[cache machanism](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-activate-response-caching-etag-last-modified)**, so using this feature you will have cache data in your app.

Retrofit cache data when you make any api call in case internet available so later on when you re call that API even internet is not available then also it will show data to user.

It also allows you to define cache size, when to cache , when to override cache etc

You don't need to manage any local database too